# How to set web folder for debugging in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, web

When I am debugging web project in visual studio the web address is for example `localhost:1234/index.html`, but when I publish project the web address will be like `*http://myserver.mydomain.com/myApplication/index.html`.

Is there a way to set in visual studio to debug it on `localhost:1234/myApplication/index.html`.

I am accessing few scripts and css and services and it will make my life easier if they will be on same level during debugging and publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project, click Properties Window and add `/myApplication` as the Virtual Path. Or you can use View->Properties Window from the main menu.